# AngularJS Pass value from directive link function to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Newbie to Angular. Very straightforward question. I have the following code.

I just want to show the file count underneath. I bind the fileCount variable to scope, but it doesn't work.

```js
var app = angular.module('fileUploader', []);

app.controller('upload', function($scope){
 $scope.fileCount = 0;
})

.directive("customDirective", function(){
 return{
  link: function(scope, el, attrs){
   el.bind("change", function(event){
    console.log(event.target.files.length);
    scope.fileCount = event.target.files.length;
   });

  }
 }

});
```

```html
 <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div ng-app="fileUploader" ng-controller="upload">
  <input custom-Directive type="file"/>
  <p>The file count is: {{fileCount}}</p>
 </div>  
 </body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The directive *does* inherit the scope properties from its parent, but it doesn't know to kick off the digest cycle whenever you change a reference to a parent property, so you have to do that manually (check out this [working jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xemuyesixu/1/edit?html,js,output)):

```
.directive("customDirective", function(){
    return{
        link: function(scope, el, attrs){
            el.bind("change", function(event){
              scope.fileCount = event.target.files.length;

              scope.$apply(); // notice this
            });
        }
    }
});
```

That'll kick off the digest cycle, and you'll see the update happen as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!